# reusing a phone(LG) bluetooth component in arduino

Tags: arduino, bluetooth

I have a older LG 150 mobile phone with bluetooth. Is it possible to remove the bluetooth component and use it in an arduino project?

My concern is that there might be some propriety assembly or instructions that would make compatibility difficult or impossible.

Anyone have any experience or suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difficulty with reusing the Bluetooth from the phone requires a little bit of background knowledge of what your options are for Bluetooth currently. The way most people implement bluetooth for hobbiest projects is to buy a module that provides you with a UART interface. They make it very easy to just pass data to it and have it pass you data back. These modules also incorporate a bluetooth stack that enables a serial tunnel to be created to the other device.

These modules are very expensive ($20-$30ish) and are not practical for a large manufacture to use. Instead they will usually implement the bluetooth stack themselves and will even go to the extent of making their own antenna (probably a PCB antenna). This makes it very difficult to just reuse in your own project.

Now there is a small chance that you could easily reuse it, but I do not know how and would bet there is not a way.

Here are some references if you want to learn more:

[Low Cost Bluetooth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/1404/low-cost-bluetooth)

[Bluetooth profiles - What is the hardware difference?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/9191/bluetooth-profiles-what-is-the-hardware-difference)

Or just look at the [bluetooth](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bluetooth) tag.